# Check which button is clicked on a ON_COMMAND_RANGE Handler function

Tags: c++, mfc

So I've made a function with multiple buttons in one function

```
ON_COMMAND_RANGE(IDC_BUTTON1, IDC_BUTTON30, CDatenbankView::DeleteButtons)
```

Now, I have to find out in my function which button is clicked.

```
void CDatenbankView::DeleteButtons(UINT nID)
{
    if (*Button1 is clicked*)
    {
        //Do something
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me? I really have no Idea. I've got 30 buttons and I don't really want to write 30 different functions.

I'm working with the `MFC`.

Comment: make an array of buttons, then you could iterate or directly access the right one.

Comment: What's wrong with `if (nID == IDC_BUTTON1) { /* Do something */ }`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function already contains the answer. You get the id of the button with nID in your handler.

```
if (nID==IDC_BUTTON1)
   // do buton 1 stuff
   ...
```